# Downloading Dell PowerEdge drivers as .inf

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell, dell-poweredge, drivers, iso

I'm using nLite to modify the Windows Server 2003 install media to include the drivers for the PowerEdge R410. I have downloaded all the drivers from Dell's website. All of the drivers I have downloaded are `.exe`.  nLite seems to be looking for `*.inf` files only.   I tried to extract them using Winrar, but I still cannot see the `.inf` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the .exe files and run them. They will extract to c:\dell\drivers\driverID.
From there, you should be able to copy the .inf files.

Comment: yes, I have done that, but some are .eve and obviously I won't get them on NLite. Included all driver on .ISO just in case anyhow so will see how I go. Thanks for input.